# Explicit Uniform Most Powerful Tests

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have that the UMP is:

$1$ if  $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 >c$ and $0$ if $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 <c$,

where $X$ consists of $n$ iid random variables with distribution $Normal(0,θ)$ where $θ$ is the variance which is $>0$  and the hypothesis are $H_0:θ=θ_0$  vs $H_1:θ=θ_1$ with $θ_1 > θ_0$ .
I am then told $θ_0 = 3, θ_1 = 4, α = 0.1 $ and $ n = 10$, and that I need to find what $c$ is.

To do this, I have said that $θ\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i^2 / θ$ ∼ $θχ^2(10)$ but I am unsure on how to advance from here. Any help much appreciated!

UPDATED:

Part b) Calculate the probability of Type 1 and Type 2 error using the values given in the previous part.

I calculated c to be $48$ when completing the last part. Knowing the definition of T1&2 errors, I say

$P$($\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i^2 >48 | Variance = 3$) is the probability of Type 1 errors, and
$P(\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i^2 <48 | Variance = 4$) is the probability of Type 2 errors. However, although I understand the intuition, I am unsure on how to calculate these probabilities at the moment, or if this is even the right approach.

Comment: Not sure why you deleted the previous post instead of editing it. You have $P_{H_0}(\sum X_i^2>c)=P_{H_0}(\frac13\sum X_i^2>\frac c3)=P(\chi^2_{10}>\frac c3)=0.1$, from which $c$ is found using chi-square fractiles.

Comment: How come it's $P_{H_0}(1/3\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i^2  > c/3$? I get that $1/3$ is $1/θ$, but when transforming from the Normal dist we are using to the Chi-Square dist, do you not need to multiply the whole thing by $θ$, given that you are dividing by it to make the normal dist the standard normal dist?

Comment: $\frac1{\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\sim \chi^2_n$. In the probability under $H_0$, I am only trying to use this fact. If you equivalently say $\sum X_i^2\sim \theta\chi^2_n$, that also leads to $P(3\chi^2_{10}>c)=0.1$

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something quite simple, but in dividing by $1/θ$ does this not change the distribution? Or is the fact that you then divide $c/3$ accounting for this?

Comment: Ok understood thank you. How would I calculate the probability of Type 1 and 2 errors from here? I think I need to find $P(\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i^2 >48$ given the Variance is $3)$ for type 1 error where $48$ is what I calculated for $c$, but I have no idea how to do this?

Comment: Is that the complete question? Edit your post to add these questions/thoughts.

Comment: I've updated the question with my thoughts on how to approach it but I'm not sure from there, or even if my thoughts are right

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, $$\frac1{\theta}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} X_i^2\sim \chi^2_{10}$$

Size of the UMP test is $0.1$, so using the above fact you have

$$P_{H_0}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i^2>c\right]=P_{H_0}\left[\frac13\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i^2>\frac c3\right]=P\left[\chi^2_{10}>\frac c3\right]=0.1$$

This indeed gives $$\frac c3=\chi^2_{0.1,10}\approx 16\implies c\approx 48$$

Your formulae for the probabilities of type I error and type II error are correct.

The former is just the size of the test, i.e. $0.1$.

And the latter is given by

\begin{align}
P_{H_1}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i^2<48\right]&=P_{H_1}\left[\frac14\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i^2<12\right]
\\&=P\left[\chi^2_{10}<12\right]
\\&\approx 0.71494
\end{align}